# How to upload a file to amazon Glacier using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I found [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/examples.html#Amazon_Glacier__Uploading_an_Archive) on the amazon aws docs.

```
var glacier = new AWS.Glacier(),
    vaultName = 'YOUR_VAULT_NAME',
    buffer = new Buffer(2.5 * 1024 * 1024); // 2.5MB buffer

var params = {vaultName: vaultName, body: buffer};
glacier.uploadArchive(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log("Error uploading archive!", err);
  else console.log("Archive ID", data.archiveId);
});
```

But I don't understand where my file goes, or how to send it to the glacier servers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is stored in the `vaultName`, what ever value you provide there. The `data.archiveId` is the representation of the file. The `body` is the file it self.

[Here is a more general overview of Glacier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/amazon-glacier-data-model.html)

[Q: How is data within Amazon Glacier organized?](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/#How_is_data_within_Amazon_Glacier_organized)

[Q: How do vaults work?](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/#How_do_vaults_work)

[Q: What is an archive?](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/#What_is_an_archive)

Cody Example: (As provided by hitautodestruct)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    glacier = new AWS.Glacier(),
    vaultName = 'YOUR_VAULT_NAME',
    // No more than 4GB otherwise use multipart upload
    file = fs.readFileSync('FILE-TO-UPLOAD.EXT');

var params = {vaultName: vaultName, body: file};
glacier.uploadArchive(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log("Error uploading archive!", err);
    else console.log("Archive ID", data.archiveId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I knew most of that except for the body part. I'll experiment with uploading a file as the body instead of the buffer.

Comment: The body is the file itself. For the sake of brevity I'm trying to add a code example but I'm guessing some moderators found it a bit too "extreme". If you could add [this code](http://jsbin.com/adiyoy/1/edit) to your answer I'll mark it as accepted.